How can I implement web traffic blacklisting through etc/hosts file in windows?
I am creating a web traffic blacklisting feature for a MDM product in windows through powershell script run by python. What I am trying to achieve is, when a domain name and username is given in the function as argument, that particular domain name is put in the etc/hosts file with 0.0.0.0 so that it is not resolved. Also the use of username here is to achieve this in user level, i.e. for each user. The script I am using is:
param(
    [string]$domainName,
    [string]$username
)

# Get the current username
$loggedInUserFull = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName

$loggedInUser = $loggedInUserFull.Split('\')[-1]
$currentUsername = $loggedInUser

# Define log file path
$logPath = "C:\Users\acer\Documents\log.txt"

# Path to the hosts file
$hostsPath = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

try {
    $hostsContent = Get-Content -Path $hostsPath -ErrorAction Stop
    $domainBlocked = $hostsContent | Where-Object { $_ -match "^\s*0\.0\.0\.0\s+$domainName\s*$" }
    $maxRetries = 3
    $currentRetry = 0

    while ($currentRetry -lt $maxRetries) {
        try {
            if ($currentUsername -eq $username -and -not $domainBlocked) {
                Add-Content -Path $hostsPath -Value "0.0.0.0 $domainName" -ErrorAction Stop
                Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Successfully blocked $domainName for user $username since current user is $currentUsername"
                break
            } elseif (-not ($currentUsername -eq $username) -and $domainBlocked) {
                $newHostsContent = $hostsContent | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "0.0.0.0 $domainName" }
                $newHostsContent | Set-Content -Path $hostsPath -ErrorAction Stop
                Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Successfully unblocked $domainName since current user is $currentUsername and rule was for user $username"
                break
            } else {
                break
            }
        } catch {
            if ($currentRetry -eq $maxRetries - 1) {
                Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Failed to modify hosts file after $maxRetries retries: $_"
                break
            } else {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
                $currentRetry++
                Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Retry $currentRetry of ${maxRetries} for $domainName and ${username}: $_"
            }
        }
    }


    $StateChangeTrigger = Get-CimClass `
        -Namespace Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler `
        -ClassName MSFT_TaskSessionStateChangeTrigger

    $TriggerUnlock = New-CimInstance `
        -CimClass $StateChangeTrigger `
        -Property @{StateChange = 8 } `
        -ClientOnly

    # Schedule this script to run at user login for all users
    $taskName = "ManageHostsFileFor${username}and${domainName}"

    $existingTask =  Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if ($existingTask) {
        Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Confirm:$false
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Existing task $taskName unregistered."

    }

    $taskDescription = "Manages hosts file at user login for all users."
    $scriptPath = $PSCommandPath
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File `"$scriptPath`" -domainName $domainName -username $username"
    $triggerLogon = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
    $principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID 'SYSTEM' -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
    
    # Create a new scheduled task settings object
    $settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
    $settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = $false  # Allow running on battery power
    $settings.StartWhenAvailable = $true


    try {
        Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Description $taskDescription -Action $action -Trigger $triggerLogon, $TriggerUnlock -Principal $principal -Settings $settings
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') Task scheduled successfully as $taskName for $username."


    }
    catch {
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') An error occurred during registration of task ${taskName}: $_"
    
    }
}
catch {
    Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value "$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') An error occurred during the process: $_"
}

This script is not working totally as expected and I have to manually run the tasks from task scheduler in windows to achieve the desired state of hosts file. Also, the file is erased fully sometimes which I guess is due to concurrency error.
Since I am new to this field, I want to know that is the process that I am following correct? Also since I will be packaging all this with other features in MSI, I am not bothering to user third party softwares (proxy or anything similar) for the task.
Also please suggest other processes if any.

The hosts file is for the whole system, not a per user setup.

@DougMaurer yes. I have tried to use the hosts file for each users by scheduling tasks which deletes entries from host file for other users and adds entries for current user each time the user logs in or unlocks the device.

@RAHULJHA So only one user can be logged in at a time?

given you are using -Cim* cmdlets everywhere else, why are you using Get-WmiObject for the username?

@stackprotector yes
